# Modify SQL query to avoid having?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, arcpy

I have a column with SQL queries to a column. These are implemented on a  function called `Select_analysis`

Form:

```
Select_analysis (in_file, out_file, {where_clause})
```

It is for simple queries and receives up until where clause.

Example:

A query like  `Select from roads where roads.width = 1`

Appears as:

```
Select_analysis(roads.shp,r_width_1m.shp, width = '1')
```

Now to the actual question:
In the field with the queries some of them contain `group by` and `having` statements.

Can you suggest a way to simplify the process so it can be used with that `Select_analysis` function?

Example:

```sql
SELECT * from OT                  -- OT is a dataset
GROUP BY OT.CA                    -- CA is a number that may exist many times.Therefore we group by that field.
HAVING ((Count(OT.OBJECTID))>1)   -- an id that appears more than once.
```

OT dataset

```
objectid     CA
1            125
2            342
3            263
1            125
```

We group by CA.

About having: it is applied to the rows that have objectid more than once. Which is the objectid 1 in this example.

My idea is to make another column that will store a result that will be accessed with a simple where clause in the `select_analysis` function

example:
OT dataset

```
objectid     CA       count_of_objid_aftergroupby
1            125           2
2            342           1
3            263           1
1            125           2
```

1) we made a new column with what the query asks

2) we simply put 'where count_of_objid_aftergroupby>1' in select_analysis.

What do you think?

Link to function documentation http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/select.htm

Comment: This is through arcpy environment and sqlalchemy won't work there.See update of question

Comment: I see you re-tagged pandas. Please post code block of how the module is implemented here (not line snippets). Also, this appears not to be a full-fledged SQL language but just an extraction tool with ArcGIS on .shp files. For aggregate or other queries, you may need to query the backend directly with a different API like pyodbc. What is backend database? Maybe your pandas code shows it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this may depend on your specific SQL implementation, but fundamentally your problem is you're trying to avoid using a 'having' while still processing an aggregate function.  A 'having' clause is just like a where clause, but processed after an aggregation step.

So I don't think you're going to find a 'Simplify This Into A Where Clause without extra structure,' answer.

I would suggest trying to sidestep the problem by creating views that do your aggregations before you get to the part where you need a HAVING clause.  Should you apply that having clause ahead of time you'll be better off.

Creating an extra column means you need to maintain it. Creating a view means you need to maintain it.  Every time you maintain the extra column you change a bunch of data, and changing a view means you change code.  Depending on your environment, one might be desirable over the other, but in most cases I would prefer the view.  Changing data is generally less reliable than changing code.

I don't know how sqlalchemy interacts with views, you might need to make those directly inside the database.  I think it would be easier to do that way.

If you absolutely can't use the database to create views, I believe ArcPy can.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-database-view.htm
and query

```
arcpy.CreateDatabaseView_management("c:/Connections/city_data.sde","trees","select objectid, owner, parcel from inventory where type = trees")
```

is the sample from that page and you may be able to plug your SQL query into it.

Comment: The problem is that this is entirely in Arcpy. It uses Python, so views isn't an option.Thanks though

Comment: Modified slightly to show how to create a view from ArcPy.

Comment: And now I can turn the initial query to a where clause? cause it still isn't possible to use a query with groupby and having in this function too. Can you explain the idea?